# How to type a text in imgeview. Right now sucessfully drawing using mouse

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

How  to type a text in imgeview... right now successfully drawing using mouse. I need to type text in same image view using keyboard...

Comment: Devi, Do you want to type text in to UIIMageVIew? That is impossible. What are you doing with mouse? No mouse control is available in iOS SDK. Please put your question clearly.

Comment: thanku for the clarification krishnan....can i add text to an image view mean typed in textfield and want that in image view please clarify...

Comment: The option provided by crypticcoder should work...

Answer (score 3):

Try superimposing a UITextView on top of your UIImageView and set appropriate frames for both so that the text appears until where you want it to appear.

Set this property for your UITextView

```
myTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
myTextView.textColor = [UIColor redColor]; //or whatever color you like based on the background image in your UIImageView.
```

Of course you will have to take care of the scrolling when the keyboard comes up after the UITextView becomes active.

If you want more assistance, please elaborate upon your question and your need.

Comment: thanku my requirement is if i want to sign message means i want to do using mouse through touch begans and touch endup, on the same view i want to add text also and i want to save as image please do needful help